# Errors while compiling an old project in newer version of Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've an old project to start work on it. Client told that it was completed in 2012, and may be with v.4.3 or some older version of Xcode. It was only targeted for iOS v.6 and  previous versions. Now client wants to make some upgrades and make it compatible for all iOS devices having iOS v.7 and/or above.

I'm running Xcode v.6.3 with iOS v.8

When I firstly open up the project and run – I got too many error (actually those should be come as warnings and not errors) from `GPUImage` framework. I solved it one-by-one. After solved those errors, when I run it again, I failed-up with few more error of SDKs not found. I can confirm that all SDKs are added properly. And its never changed, after the project was created. However its giving me errors.

Is there something that we've to setup when we run an old project (in latest Xcode and current iOS target)? Do we need to change architectures? Header search paths?

Note, all SDKs and app source code was on Github and added as submodules to the app. I have successfully cloned it in my Mac.

Please ask me if you want more information on this.

Comment: No it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But it's not running. Currently, its giving me `<FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` not found. But its already there in the project. Where, in header search paths, I can see these entries – `"${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders/Facebook-iOS-SDK/FacebookSDK"` and `"${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders/Facebook-iOS-SDK"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps could solve your problem. I am not 100% sure but it worked for me once. Worth a shot.

1) Go to Build Phases and remove the `FacebookSDK.framework`

2) Clean

3) Link back the `FacebookSDK.framework` to your project

4) Clean and Run

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm aware of this solution. What was my question is whether I need to setup something for an old project in new Xcode? I was suppose to get so many errors from `GPUImage` classes but in reality they should warnings and not errors. However a +1 from me for your efforts and correct answer for the issue.